# How to re-negotiate an accepted Job offer

Tags: salary

I am currently working in company A (size ~200) for 2 years. My salary is just 4k, they gave me an increment of 100 after a year of working. So that's a total of 4.1k. No bonus, and it's on a contract basis.

I applied and accepted a job offer from another company B (size ~1000). I am so stupid that I only asked (expected salary) for 5k. They accepted it and they offer 5.5k instead. Salary increment (evaluation) every 6 months, and bonus included. And it's a permanent contract.

I checked and did research afterward, I learned that the average salary of my profession should be around 6-7.5k. Now I am feeling demotivated and lowballed.

I have not tendered my resignation yet from the previous company A. Questions:

- shall I decline the new job offer, and just look for another company and ask for the right pay?
- shall I re-negotiate the job offer?

Help, I am so confused, and I feel that I lost my self esteem.

Comment: Ahh, well you should have done that research prior to completing negociations for company B. They did nothing wrong, you however…

Comment: @ypercubeᵀᴹ thanks, i'll focus on that idea instead and maybe just settle with the new company for now. :/

Comment: 5.5k is greater than 4k. Maybe that's a positive to take from it. It doesn't sound like they low-balled you. Looks like you offered 5k, they felt that was a bit too low (rare) and bumped it up a little. Probably prove your worth in that 6 month window and aim for an increase.

Answer (score 8):

How to re-negotiate? You don't... It would reflect poorly on you.

NEVER let the so called "market value" or "average salary" affect your satisfaction.

You have a job paying 4.1k and now you will start a job paying 5.5k with the chance of getting more every 6 months. That is almost 35% MORE than you get today. This is great: feel great about it.

You have two years of experience (if I got you right) and are therefor still a "newcomer" in your field. Don't expect to get the average salary yet... you will come there eventually.

By the way: you know what "average" means, do you? That means that there are some people earning more and some a little less than that number... that's what building an average is all about. And you are only 10% below the lower bound of the average...

If you do your job well within the next 6 months, then you will probably already get closer to the average, and another 6 months later you might already beat it...

You expected 5k. You get 5.5k: BE HAPPY! Enjoy your new job. That's the best advice to give you.

Comment: Majority of the people think they're above average. That's literally a statistical impossibility. Exactly only half will be above, and this includes the best of the best, and exactly half will be below. You'll have to know more than an average, and understand statistical distribution and standard deviation to have real understanding of where you are. Like for Torsten said, if you have only 2 years of experience and am already at the average, then your upward growth is going to be dismal for the next 40 years. Don't expect yourself to be near there yet.

Comment: @Nelson: This is why the word "average" should be avoided in favor of either "mean" or "median".  None of what you said is true of "mean", which is what is the default meaning of average (although median is certainly preferred in this scenario)

Comment: @Nelson That or nobody is average. That is what the Air Force found early on in the designs of cockpits in fighters. The average sized pilot didn't exist.